# Quartz misfires because of ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use quartz to excecute a job that daily refills a cache. This does work, but my log gets spammed with JobPersistenceExceptions like this:

> ERROR [07-13-2016 13:32:01 JobStoreSupport.java:3952 ] - **MisfireHandler: Error handling misfires: Couldn't store trigger
>   'Test.TriggerCacheReloadJob' for
>   'Test.CacheReloadJob'
>   job:com.test.tarif.jobs.CacheReloadJob
>   org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger
>   'Test.TriggerCacheReloadJob' for
>   'Test.CacheReloadJob'
>   job:com.test.tarif.jobs.CacheReloadJob [See nested exception:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.test.tarif.jobs.CacheReloadJob**]     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1212)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doUpdateOfMisfiredTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1026)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:975)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3187)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3947)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3968)
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:**
>   com.test.tarif.jobs.CacheReloadJob    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.quartz.simpl.InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.loadClass(InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.java:72)
>     at
>   org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:114)
>     at
>   org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:138)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:873)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1194)
>     ...

My quartz.properties:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = Test_Scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = 1
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.scheduler.misfirePolicy =  doNothing
```

My Scheduler:

```
public class RestStarterListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try {
            log.info("Starting");
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(CacheReloadJob.class)
                    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(07, 00)).build();
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.clear();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            log.error("Failed to start Job");
            log.error(e, e);
        }

    }
}
```

The Job.class has a zero-argument constructor, implements Job and holds the method that fills a cache. It's quite long.
As I said, the job works at 7:00, but it spams the log with these exceptions every 4 minutes.Does anyone here have a clue how to fix this or atleast how to ignore the misfires?

Comment: The exception tells you that some component wants to load a class com.test.tarif.jobs.CacheReloadJob ... and that the JVM can't load that class (meaning: there is no .class file for that class in the classpath of your JVM). So instead of ignoring this exception; I would recommend to figure where you can find the corresponding .class (probably in some library); to then make sure that your JVM has access to it.

Comment: It is in the WEB-INF\classes directory and accessible.

Comment: Well, that message says something else?!

Comment: Which is the reason I started a this topic. I do not know why quartz can't find that class.

Comment: Did you find a solution? It happens when the task is deleted and quartz still tries to load the deleted task.

Comment: Yes, if I remember correctly it was either that or that I used the wrong database. Good old misconfiguration problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a wrong name in the JOB_CLASS_NAME. Or you have several war's pointing the same database (using the same tables -prefix-) and using the same SCHED_NAME. This way a different war triggers a job that is not in its classpath.

So, either use different tables/schemas or assign a different name for every schedule.

More info:
http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/7073.page